# Como converter esse código da versão 2 para 3.4 do Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

Estou tendo dificuldades para *converter* o código abaixo para a versão *3.4* do Python, a finalidade deste código é codificar e decodificar hexadecimais, afim de criar *shellcodes*.

```py
import binascii, sys, time

RED = '\033[31m'
WHITE = '\033[37m'
RESET = '\033[0;0m'

def main():
    print("shellcode hex encode decoder")
    print("programmer : gunslinger_ <yudha.gunslinger[at]gmail.com>")
    print "what do you want to do ? %sencode%s / %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET)  
    q = raw_input("=> ")

    if q == "encode":
        inputtype = raw_input("Please input data : ")
        print "shellcode => ",
        for encoded in inputtype:
            print "\b\\x"+encoded.encode("hex"),
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print RESET

    elif q == "decode":
        inputtype = raw_input("Please input data : ")
        cleaninput = inputtype.replace("\\x","")
        print "hex       => ",cleaninput
        print "plaintext => ",
        print "\b"+cleaninput.decode("hex")

    else:
        print "wrong answer ! your choice is %sencode%s or %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET)
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Essa parte não entendi:

```
print "what do you want to do ? %sencode%s / %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET)
```

Ta certo ele definiu as cores lé em cima, e o `%sencode%s / %sdecode%s` como funciona isto? Pelo que entendi ele fez um `%s`, no começo e no final das palavras *encode* e *decode* e chamo com as cores.

```
q = raw_input("=> ")
```

Ele definiu a variável e este `=>` serial algo em específico no Python 2?

Neste parte abaixo entendi umas partes porém nem todas se alguém me explicar melhor fico grato.

```
inputtype = raw_input("Please input data : ")
print "shellcode => ",
for encoded in inputtype:
    print "\b\\x"+encoded.encode("hex"),
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Obrigado pessoal.

Comment: Já experimentou o [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)? Se isso não resolver, diga *quais são* esses "probleminhas", o que você já tentou fazer para resolvê-los, e no que quer que a gente ajude. À primeira vista, uns parênteses após os `print`s resolveriam a maior parte dos problemas...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Por que não cria uma resposta? acho que deve ser interessante mostrar esse processo de tradução.

Comment: @qmechanik Estava apenas dando uma dica rápida que *talvez* resolvesse os problemas sem precisar pensar muito. Mas na realidade, uma resposta como a sua que explica as diferenças entre as versões é bem mais útil. O `2to3`, pelo que eu li (nunca o usei de fato), seria apenas uma ajuda para converter códigos grandes, mas não garante que o resultado seja um código correto e funcional (i.e. não dispensa a revisão cuidadosa do código convertido).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deverá ser feita algumas mudanças no código para que funcione do modo esperado no Python 3.

- Em versões anteriores ao Python 3 o [**print era uma instrução**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) ([*statement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29)), a partir do Python 3, ele é considerado [**uma função**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/), e por isso alguns detalhes da sintaxe mudaram, como o uso obrigatório de parênteses, `()`.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- A partir do Python 3, a função *built-in* `raw_input()` [**foi renomeada**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/) para [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#input).

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- No Python 3 não é necessário usar a vírgula no final para suprimir uma nova linha.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- A partir do [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html) os métodos que tratavam sobre a codificação e decodificação foram substituídos pelas funções do módulo [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-codecs).

  Python 3.4, modo errado:

  ```
  b"hello".decode("hex")
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs
  ```

  Python 3.4, modo correto:

  ```
  >>> from codecs import encode, decode
  >>> encode(b"hello", "hex")
  b'68656c6c6f'
  >>> decode(b"68656c6c6f", "hex")
  b'hello'
  ```
- > Essa parte não entendi:

  ```
  print "what do you want to do ? %sencode%s / %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET)
  ```

  As quatro ocorrências do formato `%s` serão substituídas pelos valores de `RED`, `RESET`, `WHITE` e `RESET`. O `print` imprimirá:

  ```
  print "what do you want to do ? \033[31mencode\033[0;0m / \033[37mdecode\033[0;0m"
  ```

  Isso imprimirá na tela palavras com uma cor diferente, outras combinações de cores podem ser vistas [**aqui**](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).
- > q = raw_input("=> ") --> ele definiu a variável e este => serial algo em específico no python 2

  O `=>` é o texto que será apresentado e que irá receber a entrada do usuário.
- > Neste parte abaixo entendi umas partes porém nem todas se alguém me explicar melhor fico grato.

  ```
  inputtype = raw_input("Please input data : ") # Recebe a entrada do usuário
  print "shellcode => ",                        # Imprime "shellcode =>" e elimina a nova linha
  for encoded in inputtype:                     # Percorre cada letra da variável "inputtype"
      print "\b\\x"+encoded.encode("hex"),
      sys.stdout.flush()                        # Imprime diretamente na saída padrão "stdout"
      time.sleep(0.5)                           # Espera 30s
  ```

O código *convertido* para Python 3 deve ficar assim:

```
import sys, time, binascii
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

RED = '\033[31m'
WHITE = '\033[37m'
RESET = '\033[0;0m'

def main():
    print("shellcode hex encode decoder")
    print("programmer : gunslinger_ <yudha.gunslinger[at]gmail.com>")
    print("what do you want to do ? {0}encode{1} / {2}decode{3}".format(RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET))
    q = input("=> ")

    if q == "encode":
        inputtype = input("Please input data : ")
        print ("shellcode => ")
        for encoded in inputtype:
            print ("\\x{0}".format(binascii.hexlify(bytes(encoded, 'utf-8')).decode()))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print (RESET)

    elif q == "decode":
        inputtype = input("Please input data : ")
        cleaninput = inputtype.replace("\\x","")
        print ("hex       => {0}".format(inputtype))
        print ("plaintext => {0}".format(binascii.unhexlify(cleaninput).decode('utf-8')))
    else:
        print ("wrong answer ! your choice is %sencode%s or %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET))
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Uma versão mais *limpa* e com algumas modificações:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, binascii

cor = {'vermelho': '\033[1;31m', 'branco': '\033[1;34m', 'sem_cor': '\033[0;0m'}

def shellcode(opcao, texto):
    resultado = ""
    if opcao == 'e':
        resultado += ''.join("\\x{0}".format(binascii.hexlify(bytes(s, 'utf-8')).decode()) for s in texto)
    elif opcao == 'd':
        texto = texto.replace('\\x', '')
        resultado = binascii.unhexlify(texto).decode()
    return resultado

def main():
    opcoes = "{0}encode{1} / {2}decode{3} ou sair".format(cor['vermelho'], cor['sem_cor'], cor['branco'], cor['sem_cor'])
    print("O que quer fazer? {0}".format(opcoes))
    while True:
        try:
            questao = input("Opcao: ").lower()
            dados = input("Dados: ")
            codigo = ""

            if questao in ['encode', 'enc', 'e']:
                codigo = shellcode('e', dados)
            elif questao in ['decode', 'dec', 'd']:
                codigo = shellcode('d', dados)
            elif questao in ['sair', 's']:
                sys.exit()
            else:
                sys.exit("Opcao inválida! Opcoes: {0}".format(opcoes))

            print("{0}: {1}".format(questao, codigo))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Pó amigo me ajudo muitos nas minhas dúvidas, eu vi tu colocou o código nos formatados novos, porém queria que você não tive-se colocado. E que eu gosto de colocar a cabeça pra funcionar, se eu tive-se dúvida perguntaria aqui de novo. Como sou novato em python e bom pra colocar a cabeça funcionar, mais vou fazer do meu jeito aqui o código e depois posto aqui como ficou. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @GlaucioFonseca Entendi, em todo caso postei uma versão mais limpa e corrigi um erro na parte do *decode*, se tiver algo a mais que eu possa ajudar, diga. =)

Comment: Valeu mano obrigado.

Comment: @GlaucioFonseca Se possível marque a resposta como aceita. =)

Comment: Já marquei como resposta aceita @qmechanik

Comment: @GlaucioFonseca Para marcar como aceita clique sobre o ✔ depois ela fica verde. Uma outra coisa, se quiser usar `codecs.encode/decode` ao invés de `binascii.hexlify/unhexlify` também da certo.

Comment: Feito mano obrigado.